# android onpause not called when using navgraph

Tags: android, fragment, lifecycle

Using androids navgraph/navhost seems useful. However the lifecycle of fragments has changed when compared to the previous fragmentmanager method replace.

Prevoiusly I called replace with fragment manager and the fragments onPause method was called before transitioning to a new fragment ensuring I had notice the user had navigated away.

Now, using a navgraph, the onresume is called but onpause, onSaveInstanceState and onstop are not when the fragment is not longer visible.

There are many old answers to this question on SO that are no longer relevent and I see some low ranked answers that are addressing the issue by not using navgraph and navhost.

My question is simple and as follows.

The user navigates away from a fragment(or navhostfragment) using the navhost/graph. The fragment is not visible. What is the appropriate hook for executing a bit of closing code.

also I cannot create the navhost, navgraph or navcontroller tags which should be in this question

Answer (score 0):

Navgraph maintains the fragments in the stack so you can't guarantee when it will be paused. However when the user is navigating to and from the fragment you can use the oncreateView and onDestroyView. I should have known better as I use the oncreate very consistently.

This override method is guaranteed to be called when navigating away.

```
    @Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```